# How to count how many different nodes are in my linkedlist?

Tags: java, collections, linked-list, nodes

I made my own Node class and my own LinkedList class, I would like to build a function that counts how many different Node are in my LinkedList.

I have tried with this code but it does not work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < quantityOfNode(); i++) {
    boolean isDistinct = true;

    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        if (node.getInfo().equals(node.getNext().getInfo())) {
            isDistinct = false;
        }
    }
    if (isDistinct) {
        nbDistinct++;
    }
    if (node.getNext().getNext() != null) {
        node= node.getNext();
    }
}
```

exemple :

```
        list.add(3);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(5);
    list.add(3);
    list.add(3);
    list.add(8);
```

this is supose to give me 4 different node, but i get 5, because the node 3 is counted 2 times

Now i have tried to travel with a second node in my j loop and for the same input it now gives me 2 instead of 4

here is the new code i tried and still not working :

```
            for (int i = 0; i < quantityOfNode(); i++) {
            boolean isDistinct = true;
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (node.getInfo().equals(node2.getInfo())) {
                    isDistinct = false;

                }

                if (node2.getNext() != null) {
                    node2 = node2.getNext();
                }

            }
            if (isDistinct) {
                nbDistinct++;
            }
            if (node.getNext() != null) {
                node= node.getNext();
            }
        }
```

Comment: In what way does it not work? Give an example of input and expected output and actual output.

Comment: What does the `length()` method do?

Comment: list.add(3);
  list.add(2);
  list.add(5);
  list.add(3);
  list.add(3);
  list.add(8);

i am supose to have 4 different node, but i get 5

Comment: Does `list.add(x)` add to the beginning or the end.

Comment: it adds at the end of the linkedlist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `j` loop is not stepping `node` forward - it is always comparing the same pair of nodes and thus has no function.

You need something like:

```
...
Node earlierNode = rootNode;
for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    if (earlierNode.getInfo().equals(node.getInfo())) {
        isDistinct = false;
    }
    earlierNode = earlierNode.getNext();
}
...
```

Comment: @pharaon450 - Added suggestion.

Comment: thank you im still trying it still does not work :( maybe is there a way i can chat with you, im new to this site

Comment: I think you should try @Patashu's suggestions. That answer covers the issues you have. Perhaps post your new code **after** your old to see where you are now wrong.

Comment: i posted the new code and it still not working it gives me 2, instead of 4

Comment: You are still not walking a new `Node` up the list in your `j` loop. See my code where I suggest `Node earlierNode = rootNode;
for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {` and @Patashu's code where he suggests `Node node2 = firstNode(); for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27054/discussion-between-pharaon450-and-oldcurmudgeon)

Comment: i got it i needed to declare my second node inside my i loop
it is working for now thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Set.

```
Set set = new HashSet();
Node cur = list.head;
while(cur != null) {
    set.add(cur.getInfo());
    cur = cur.getNext();
}
return set.size();
```

This doesn't use generics because I don't konw what types you have for getInfo.

Alternatively, if you cannot use a set, you should try to get rid of your 'index' variables (i and j). You really want to focus your application logic on what you actually have, not values implicitly calculated. You want to stop when your current node becomes null, not when you've advanced a certain number of times. If that's not logical let me know.

For each node, check the nodes before it to see if that node exists. I start at the head each time because I don't know if you have double links or not. It's the same complexity either way, but on a sorted list this is less optimal.

```
Node cur = list.head; // for each node
int nbDistinct = 0;
while(cur != null) { // go until we're out of nodes
    Node check = list.head; // check the first node
    boolean isDistinct = true; // assume distinct
    while(check != cur && isDistinct) { // stop if we found a match OR if our checker caught up to our current node
        isDistinct |= !check.getInfo().equals(cur.getInfo()); // essentially "if(check.getInfo().equals(cur.getInfo()) isDistinct = true;"
        check = check.getNext(); // advance the checker
    }
    if(isDistinct) nbDistinct++;
    cur = cur.getNext(); // advance the current node
}
```

Comment: Sorry i dont know about Set so im trying to not use it but thank you

Comment: I also have an alternative solution, with commentary.

Comment: i will try it thank you but can you tell me why should i stop when i found a match ? my goal is to know how many different node are in my linkedlist

Comment: You stop when you find a match because `isDistinct` isn't ever going to get truer than it already is.

Answer (score 2):

First problem:

If your for loop is written such that it does not go over the length of the linked list:

`for (int i = 0; i < length(); i++) {`

Then why do you need this?

```
            if (node.getNext().getNext() != null) {
                node= node.getNext();
            }
```

In particular, this code might mean that a node just before the end is evaluated twice, because the node beyond it is `null`. It is not necessarily making your algorithm wrong, but it smells bad and I don't like it.

Second problem:

```
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (node.getInfo().equals(node.getNext().getInfo())) {
                    isDistinct = false;
                }
            }
```

This is a faulty way to calculate duplicates because you do not store and advance the position of the second node you are comparing against. Try something like

```
            Node node2 = firstNode(); //idk what method gets the first node :)
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (node.getInfo().equals(node2.getInfo())) {
                    isDistinct = false;
                    break; //optimization, stop as soon as we find a duplicate
                }
                node2 = node2.GetNext();
            }
```

Finally, **whenever faced with code that does not work, attach a debugger, step through it and notice when the code does not do what you expect it to.** This will solve all logic errors quickly with just a small amount of observation. Even if you don't have access to the debugger, you can use `print` statements to print the value of various variables and when certain code branches execute and compare to what you expected would happen.

Comment: He's using a double for loop to compare every element against every other element.

Comment: @corsiKa He only checks against nodes earlier in the list than the current node, so that you count the first instance of a duplicated node correctly and skip all the others. Plus, it was not working because it did not have a second node that it advanced through the list, it would just compare the node against its next node over and over and over `i` times.

Comment: @Patashu so you suggest me to add another node for my j loop ?

Comment: @Patashu can you tell me more about adding another node ? do you means i create another node that start at the beggining of my linkedlist and travels with j loop ??

Comment: @pharaon450 Please examine the fourth code snippet in my answer. Yes, you make a second node, that starts at the beginning and travels with the j loop - that way you compare node i to node 0, to node 1, to node 2... to node i-1, for each value of j, stopping just before node i so you don't compare the node to itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Set

```
Set<Node> mySet = new HashSet<Node>(list);
answer = mySet.size();
```

this depends on you implementing hashCode and equals in your node class, alternatively you could use TreeSet and a Comparator.

```
Comparator<Node> myComparator = new MyCustomComparator();// you have to define your comparator.
Set<Node> mySet = new TreeSet<Node>(myComparator);
mySet.addAll(list);
answer = mySet.size();
```

Comment: im sorry i dont know about Set so i cant use it but thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your first time around the `i` loop your `j` loop does nothing (because it starts at 0 and continues while `j < i` which it isn't) so you leave `distinct` set true without comparing anything with anything.

Try starting `i` at 1.

Comment: You misunderstand the point of the second loop - it's meant to see if this node has any duplicates EARLIER in the list than it. Your suggestion would make each node also compare with itself, and so no node would be considered a non duplicate.,

Comment: You still increment `nbDistinct` once the first time around without comparing anything with anything.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon yes because the first node is disctint

Comment: @pharaon450 - You are correct - see my second idea [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15671562/823393)